# Finding joint distribution for the following

Tags: statistics

I am trying to do the following problem 
Suppose that $X_1,...,X_n\stackrel{iid}\sim N(0,1)$. Define $$\bar{X}_k=\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}X_i,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{for }k=2,3,.....,n
$$

(i) What is the joint distribution of $(X_2-\bar{X}_2,X_3-\bar{X}_3,...,X_n-\bar{X}_n)$?

(ii) What is the distribution of $$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k-1}{k}(X_k-\bar{X}_k)^2$$
Now I am thinking to find the pdf of $X_2-\bar{X}_2,X_3-\bar{X}_3,...,X_n-\bar{X}_n$ separately and then multiply them since they are independent.

To find the pdf of $X_2-\bar{X}_2$ I started by $$U=X_2-\bar{X}_2=X_2-X_1$$ $$V=X_2$$ after some calculation I got $$f_{UV}(u,v)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2} e^{-v^2+uv}
$$

So to find the pdf of U we have to find $$f_U(u)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2} e^{-v^2+uv}\,\,dv$$

After some calculation I got
$$f_U(u)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}$$
 I don't know whether I am in the right direction since it's involving a lot of calculation. I am wondering is there any other way that I can try. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: $-v^2 + uv = -(v - \tfrac12u)^2 + \tfrac14 u^2$. Also [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5E(-x%5E2)+from+-inf+to+inf)

Comment: @this-user66081 Thanks a lot

Comment: I got it finally. I was doing it wrong..........